# Is it permissible to eat with non-Muslims?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food

Is **eating on the same table with non-Muslims** (Christians, Jews, Hindus, etc) allowed? The assumption is that you would be eating halal food such as vegetables, and that non-Muslims would eat food which they consider permissible according their religion.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Do you mean "are we allowed to eat (halal/vegetarian/etc.) food from Christains/Jews/Hindus etc." or "are we allowed to eat at the same table as them"?

Comment: @ashes999: Eating at the same table actually.

Comment: I've edited your question, please verify that it's reflective of what you want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Islam as a *deen* (comprehensive way of life) generally permits everything, and screens out those things which are haraam.

From Usool ul-Fiqh, we learn that "all actions (which are not acts of worship) are halal until proven haram." The default ruling would apply here: you would assume that it's okay, unless shari'ah puts some conditions or exclusions on it.

Some exclusions do exist. Consider this hadith:

> Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day, let him not sit at a table
>   where alcohol is being passed around. ([Tirmidhi, Saheeh](http://thethinkingmuslim.wordpress.com/tag/alcohol/))

In this case, Allah's messenger did not permit us to sit at the table where people are drinking. Doing so would be considered sinful.

An additional ruling that would apply here would be the ruling of mixed gatherings. Islam in general does not permit mixing of genders without a very solid reason. This is pretty well-known; you can find an extensive list of proofs in [this IslamQA fatwa](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/1200/mixed%20gatherings). Their introduction says:

> The meeting together, mixing, and intermingling of men and women in
>   one place, the crowding of them together, and the revealing and
>   exposure of women to men are prohibited by the Law of Islam
>   (Shari'ah). These acts are prohibited because they are among the
>   causes for fitnah (temptation or trial which implies evil
>   consequences), the arousing of desires, and the committing of
>   indecency and wrongdoing.

This would apply at all social gatherings, including sitting at tables which are mixed. This applies double if the sitting is in khulwa (isolation from others), such as a date.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Either you just missed to conclude or explicitly say that it is permissible or you have doubts about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can share food with non-muslims as long as it's Hallal and Allah know better.

In Surat Al Maa'ida Ayah 5:

> اليوم أحل لكم الطيبات وطعام الذين أوتوا الكتاب حل لكم وطعامكم حل لهم والمحصنات من المؤمنات والمحصنات من الذين أوتوا الكتاب من قبلكم إذا آتيتموهن أجورهن محصنين غير مسافحين ولا متخذي أخدان ومن يكفر بالإيمان فقد حبط عمله وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين 
>   http://quran.com/5/5

And here is Ibn Kathir explanation: http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=49&ID=375

So if we can eat Christians and Jews food (their sacrifices) I don't see why we shouldn't share and Allah know better.

Also, you need to represent islam and show how beautiful it is to others by all means allowed.

May Allah help you succeed in your life.

Answer (score 0):

Al-hamdu lillah (praise be to Allah). There is no objection for a Muslim to eat from food that a kaafir (unbeliever), whether polytheist or otherwise, has cooked, as the issue of cooking does not involve slaughtering according to Islamic guidelines so that we would require the person to be from ahl il-kitaab (People of the Book) among the kuffar. In fact, it is only a matter of cooking, so the only issues that concern us are cleanliness and the avoidance of najasa (impurity), and likewise that nothing haram (forbidden) is mixed with the food such as khamr (wine or alcoholic beverages) or lard.

May Allah protect us from harm, evil and the things he has forbidden (al-    muharramaat).

Answer (score -1):

"Is eating on the same table with non-Muslims (Christians, Jews, Hindus, etc) allowed? The assumption is that you would be eating halal food such as vegetables, and that non-Muslims would eat food which they consider permissible according their religion."

The Above question was still not answered appropriately by anyone.

Recently I came across such incident seeking for answers.

I am a Hindu,Living in Saudi Arabia for 9 Years for Work. I used to mingle with Arab/Saudi friends on all official parties at professional environment. I had shared food in the Same plate with them since last 9 years..

To my surprise this time, while I was eating lunch along with my colleagues, they raised a discussion that If non-Muslims are allowed to eat food along with Muslims in the same Platter. After a lot of discussions in Arabic among them, they decided that it is not appropriate for both of them to Share the Same Platter of Food.(Like Mandi, Kharouf, Kabsa in a Single Full big Plate). 
I was provided a Pack Lunch Since then and was told to eat in private and not to eat with them anymore !!!! (If I tell the Company where it happened, everyone will Faint, hahaha)

The very moment I thought, "What a Shame these guys have committed to Islam"

If it was ever written anywhere in Quran as these guys Claim it. then Oh My “Father, forgive them and the religion, for they know not what they do.”

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: You claim that "The Above question was still not answered appropriately by anyone.", but you don't seem to answer it yourself rather than quoting your experience as a non-Muslim. There are indeed fatwa's which clearly say that eating with non-Muslims is allowed (If halal-conditions of food and beverage etc. are met) it is even allowed (by hadith) to eat from plates and pots of people of the book (same conditions as before).

Comment: As a non-muslim who has lived in an islamic country for over 20 years, Muslims do not approve of you eating with them, so avoid it.